# Python combinar líneas de dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, itertools

Estoy intentando combinar los valores de una columna de un dataframe (letra) para mostrar por pareja de valores y posteriormente realizar cálculos. Resumidamente tengo esta situación inicial:

| letra | x_1 | y1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 3 |
| A | 0 | 2 |
| C | 5 | 6 |

Y necesito generar todas las combinaciones posibles de esta manera:

| letra | x_1 | y1 | letra2 | x_2 | y2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 2 | A | 0 | 2 |
| A | 0 | 2 | B | 1 | 3 |
| A | 0 | 2 | A | 0 | 2 |
| A | 0 | 2 | C | 5 | 6 |
| B | 1 | 3 | A | 0 | 2 |

Lo he intentado con el siguiente código pero no puedo realizar cálculos con las columnas (p.e. x_1 + y_1) por crear un subindice a,b:

```
from itertools import combinations

a, b = map(list, zip(*combinations(df_1.index, 2)))

d = pd.concat(
    [df_1.loc[a].reset_index(), df_1.loc[b].reset_index()],
    keys=['a', 'b'], axis=1)
```

Alguien sabría ayudarme para resolver y poder operar correctamente con todas las posibles combinaciones?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar el método `combinations_with_replacement()` ([documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)) para que te devuelva todas las combinaciones incluyendo la combinación de los datos de la misma fila (Por ejemplo fila 0 con fila 0).

```
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(df.index,2))
```

Teniendo las combinaciones vas a poder utilizar `loc` para obtener los datos de cada fila. Puedes guardar esos datos en `dataframe` temporales para que sea mas sencillo manejar la información.

```
df1 = df.loc[pd.Index([i[0]])].copy()
df2 = df.loc[pd.Index([i[1]])].copy()
```

Luego renombras las columnas de uno de tus `dataframe` temporales para poder unir los datos en una fila con el método `merge()` ([documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)).

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'letra': 'letra2', 'x_1': 'x_2', 'y_1': 'y_2'})
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

Y para finalizar, si utilizamos un nuevo `dataframe` podemos concatenar todas las filas para tener la información organizada. Utilizamos el método `reset_index()` para que el índice empiece de 0

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools 

df = pd.DataFrame({'letra': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'x_1': [0, 1, 0, 5],
                   'y_1': [2, 3 ,2 ,6]})

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['letra', 'x_1', 'y_1', 'letra2', 'x_2', 'y_2'])
for i in list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(df.index,2)):
    df1 = df.loc[pd.Index([i[0]])].copy()
    df2 = df.loc[pd.Index([i[1]])].copy()
    df2 = df2.rename(columns={'letra': 'letra2', 'x_1': 'x_2', 'y_1': 'y_2'})
    df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
    result = pd.concat([result,df3])
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Al imprimir result obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
    letra   x_1 y_1 letra2  x_2 y_2
0   A       0   2   A       0   2
1   A       0   2   B       1   3
2   A       0   2   C       0   2
3   A       0   2   D       5   6
4   B       1   3   B       1   3
5   B       1   3   C       0   2
6   B       1   3   D       5   6
7   C       0   2   C       0   2
8   C       0   2   D       5   6
9   D       5   6   D       5   6
```